# Integrate squared sum

Tags: calculus, statistics

This is a mathematical question, but with a statistical flavour.

A little background:
I have $N$ IID observations denoted by $w[n]$, from a uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}[0,\beta]$. Now, I know an unbiased estimator of $\beta$:

$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{2}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w[n]$$

and the variance of a uniform distribution is $\frac{\beta}{12}$

so a method to compute an estimator of $E[\hat{\sigma^2}]$ is to do this:

$$E[\hat{\beta^2}] = E[\hat{\beta}]^2 + \operatorname{Var}(w[n])$$

It's simpler because I know the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances. But I'm trying to prove it using the expectation integral, and then I must solve:

$$\frac{1}{12}E[\hat{\beta^2}]=\frac{2}{12N^2\beta} \int_0^\beta \left(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w[n]\right)^2 \, dw$$

where $\beta$ is a constant.

**How does one integrate a squared sum like this?**

The substitution method didn't seem to work very well. I tried to set $u=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w[n]$ such that $du=N$, and I integrate, and get the anti-integral $\frac{1}{3}\Big(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w[n]\Big)^3$. This gives a solution:

$E[\hat{\beta^2}]=\frac{2N\beta^2}{36}$, but the answer is supposed to be

$$E[\hat{\beta^2}]=\frac{1}{12}\Big(\beta^2+\frac{\beta^2}{36N}\Big)$$

Has anyone solved this before?

Comment: Your integration doesn't make any sense.  The $N$ different values of $w[n]$ are taken from different copies of the distribution, so you can't evaluate the expectation with just a single integral... you should integrate $N$ times, but clearly you're confused about how to do this.  It's much simpler to stick to the language of expected values instead of trying to express this as an integral.  Use linearity of expectation $E[X+Y] = E[X]+E[Y]$, and try to do $E[(w[0]+w[1])^2]$ first before tackling the general case.  You'll also need to use $E[XY] = E[X] E[Y]$ when $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: A "better" unbiased estimator is $\frac{N+1}{N} \max(w[n])$

Comment: Why do you write "Where" with a capital "W" rather than lower case when it's not at the beginning of the sentence?  It seems as if more than half the people who post here do that.  Is there some sort of software that you use that makes you do that? $\qquad$

Comment: The variance is $\beta^2/12$, not $\beta/12$. $\qquad$

Comment: You say you want an estimator of $\operatorname{E}\left( \widehat \sigma^2 \right)$, but you've never said what $\sigma^2$ is or what $\widehat\sigma^2$ is.  That leaves your question quite unclear. $\qquad$

Comment: Not quite on topic, but maybe you'll find it useful at some point to know that this particular unbiased estimator of $\beta$ is very ill-behaved and inefficient.  In particular, sometimes it is smaller than the largest observed value, and then you know, based on the observable data alone, that although this estimator is right on average, you're looking at a very non-average situation.  A far better unbiased estimator is $(N+1)/N$ times the largest obwerved value of $w$. $\qquad$